# Markov Chain with Memory

Tags: graph-theory, markov-chains, mathematical-modeling

One of the defining characteristics of a Markov Chain is that it is memoryless: the next state depends only on the current state, and not on the set of preceding states.

I'm looking for a mathematical structure that is, essentially, a Markov Chain with memory. All the same, except for that the next state depends on some set of preceding states. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Two classes of models: Markov chains of higher order, and VLMC (varying length Markov chains).

Comment: Yes in a way. I am actually working with first order Markov models which requires information of the current state and previous state. Such a model was a bit confusing to me when I first came across them, as it seems to contravene that Markov condition.

Comment: Maybe, as Markov Chains are isomorphic to probabilistic automatons, those that you want might be seen by probabilistic pushdown automatas.

Comment: Variable-order Markov models are also relevant here.

Comment: Yeah, this is what VLMC (in my first comment) refers to.

Comment: Got something from this answer?

Comment: @Did Yeah, the terminology reference was helpful (though more mathematical detail might have made it better?).

Comment: Sorry but it seems difficult to add more substance to answer such a vague question.

Answer (score 3):

Two classes of models: Markov chains of higher order, and Varying Length Markov Chains (VLMCs, also known as Variable-Order Markov Models).